# Detecting if a geocoordinate point is land or ocean in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find whether a given location with latitude/longtitude is a land or water. Is there any library in Java that gives me a result of my question?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: basically, you need a spatial dataset of either land or water (doesn't really matter which) - then you do a point in polygon to see if it falls in any of the polygons.

Comment: ...or you call a web-based service such as `geonames` which I think can do that for you. I don't know if there's a Java library to make calling it easier or if it is simple to build an HTTP query in Java and do it yourself. See http://geonames.org for more, specifically I think the "ocean" query in the API.